# Basic pointer / reference problems

Tags: c++

Thanks so much for your comments, I'm new here and not familiar with protocol. Here's my complete example. And here's what I get on execution

in vertex ctor
loading vertex[ 0] = xxx
in vertex ctor
loading vertex[ 1] = xxx
in vertex ctor
loading vertex[ 2] = xxx
in vertex ctor
loading vertex[ 3] = xxx
in vertex ctor
loading vertex[ 4] = xxx
in vertex ctor
loading vertex[ 5] = xxx
in vertex ctor
loading vertex[ 0] = xxx
calculateCosts
got vertex named xxx
moving vertex named xxx
done
Segmentation fault

```
    #include <iostream> 
#include <vector>   
#include <cassert>  
#include <limits>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iterator>

// required compile option g++ homeWork2.cpp -std=c++0x

using namespace std;

const int infinity = numeric_limits<int>::infinity();
//const   vertex* nullPtr = 0;

class vertex
{
public:
    string name;
    vertex(string name = "undefined")
    {
        cout << "in vertex ctor " << endl;
        name = "AAAAAA";
        value = infinity;
        prev_vertex = NULL;
    }
    void set_value(int& value)
    {
        assert(value > 0);
        value = value;
    }
    int get_value()
    {
        return value;
    }
    void set_prev_vertex(vertex& prev_vertex)
    {
        prev_vertex = prev_vertex;
    }
    vertex* get_prev_vertex()
    {
        return prev_vertex;
    }

private:
    int value;
    vertex * prev_vertex;
};


class graph
{
public:
    graph(int graphSize = 50)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < graphSize; ++i)
        {
            vertex* pV = new vertex("vertex name");
            pV->name = "xxx";
            cout << "loading vertex[ " << i << "] = " << pV->name << endl;
            vertices.push_back(pV);
        }
    }

//    vector<vertex> get_neighbors(int i);

    void push_Vertex(unsigned position, vertex* v);
    void remove_Vertex(unsigned position);
    vertex* get_Vertex(unsigned position);
    int size();
    vector<vertex*> get_neighbors(int i);

    ~graph()
    {
        while (vertices.size() > 0)
        {
//          cout << "removing vertices[ " << vertices.size() << "] = " << vertices.back() << endl;
            delete vertices.back();
            vertices.pop_back();
        }
    }

private:
    int graph_count;
    vector<vertex*> vertices;
};

void graph::push_Vertex(unsigned position, vertex* v)
{
//      cout << "copying vertex named " << *v->name << endl;
//        assert(v!=NULL);
        vertices[position] = v;
//      vertices.push_back(v);
}
void graph::remove_Vertex(unsigned position)
{
    vertices.erase(vertices.begin()+position);
}
vertex* graph::get_Vertex(unsigned position)
{
//  vector<int>::iterator iter = vertices.begin()+=position;
    vertex* pV = vertices.at(position);
    cout << "got vertex named " << pV->name << endl;
    return pV;
}

vector<vertex*> graph::get_neighbors(int i)
{
    vector<vertex*> vertices;
    /* load the it neighbors*/
    return vertices;
}

int graph::size()
{
    return vertices.size();
}

void moveVertex(graph& fromSet, graph& toSet, int position, int value)
{
    vertex* v = fromSet.get_Vertex(position);
    cout << "moving vertex named " << v->name << endl;
    toSet.push_Vertex(0, v);

}

void calculateCosts(graph& unvisitedSet, graph& visitedSet)
{
    moveVertex(unvisitedSet, visitedSet, 0, 0);
    for (int i =0; i < unvisitedSet.size(); ++i) {
//  do the algo process ...        
    }
}

// 
int main()
{

//    adjacency_list adjList = adjacency_list(6);
//    cost_list costList = cost_list(6);
    graph visitedSet = graph(6);
    graph unvisitedSet = graph(1);
    cout << "calculateCosts" << endl;
    calculateCosts(visitedSet, unvisitedSet);

    cout << "done" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2):

```
        vertex* v = new vertex("vertex nbr "+i);
```

In C++ you can't use `operator+` on `const char*` and `int`. Must construct a string in some other way. I'm surprised that compiler did not write a warning about it, let alone stopped right there.

EDIT: I now see the line "calculateCosts moving vertex named done Segmentation fault". It is very unremarkable, and I didn't notice it the first time, but now I see that it is the output of the program. It appears that to code that causes the segmentation fault is in one of the destructors. Does your debugger has functionality of pausing the execution when segfault happens? Can you turn in on? Can you debug step by step through your code, including the code in the destructors? What happens if you debug step by step?

Very important: what do the `vertex` constructor and destructor look like?

This post is supposed to provide an answer, but I'm giving you more questions instead. That is because your own question is lacking relevant information. You gave some code, which is fine, but I can't compile that code to reproduce the error. Make an effort to reduce your example code to bare minimum that reproduces the error. It may take significant time, and you may very well find the problem yourself. That would be the perfect outcome.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've fixed it. But it does not have anything to do with the pointer issues I believe

Comment: @user2947811 It is difficult to see what the problem is because your code does show [short, self containing, correct example](http://sscce.org/). You don't even post a message of the error, nor where does it happen in the code. We're not mind readers.

Comment: @user2947811 I edited the "answer". Note the question marked as "very important".

Comment: you are correct about the dtor, removing it removed the segfault

Comment: THANKS! I'll look into what I've done wrong here, but see now I was chasing the wrong rat ...